# python email добавить текст в письмо

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, rfc

Я проверяю вложения в письме через антивирусную систему, если вложение вредоносное или подозрительное его необходимо удалить из письма и добавить текст о том что это вложение было удалено.
Но я столкнулся с некоторыми сложностями, если письмо содержит inline вложение (например картинку встроенную в письмо) то добавление в конец информации ни к чему не приводит, эта информация просто не отображается почтовыми клиентами при просмотре письма.
Я использую письмо следующего содержания(удалено содержимое картинки):

```
To: nmikaev <nmikaev@tip.avsw.ru>
From: nmikaev <nmikaev@tip.avsw.ru>
Subject: test18
Message-ID: <5bf8356f-2cad-bb52-1644-344b25a6a3fe@tip.avsw.ru>
Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2017 16:39:47 +0300
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101
 Thunderbird/52.5.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="------------9D100498B76DCCA2302346E9"
Content-Language: en-US

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------9D100498B76DCCA2302346E9
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

test18

test18


--------------9D100498B76DCCA2302346E9
Content-Type: multipart/related;
 boundary="------------F4FDF24DEF3F140B04A4F455"


--------------F4FDF24DEF3F140B04A4F455
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <p>test18</p>
    <p><img src="cid:part1.FFAD31E9.10EFE63D@tip.avsw.ru" alt=""></p>
    <p>test18</p>
  </body>
</html>

--------------F4FDF24DEF3F140B04A4F455
Content-Type: image/jpeg;
 name="oplpbkaaobmmkala.jpeg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part1.FFAD31E9.10EFE63D@tip.avsw.ru>
Content-Disposition: inline;
 filename="oplpbkaaobmmkala.jpeg"

HERE IMAGE CONTENT

--------------F4FDF24DEF3F140B04A4F455--

--------------9D100498B76DCCA2302346E9
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Removed oplpbkaaobmmkala.jpeg with hash: 4b002716ede36b1f8da0ec3543cdb6996b50d943d1ba789a8fd39e3d467174e3

--------------9D100498B76DCCA2302346E9--
```

В конце информация добавлена уже. 
Использую следующий код:

```
text = ''
if self.attachments_pool:
    for attachment in self.attachments_pool:
        text+='Removed ' + attachment.getFilename() +' with hash: ' + attachment.getHash() + '\n'
        text = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    self.msg.attach(text)
```

Однако если письмо не содержит inline вложений, то информация корректно отображается.
Возможно проблема в том что test18 прописывается дважды в text/plain и в html. А между ними должно быть изображение, может надо выделять основной какой то объект email.Message в который добавлять новый текст. Как это сделать ? И я так понимаю что метод attach не совсем подходит для этих целей ?

И еще , как можно эффективно удалять вложения Content-Disposition: inline или Content-Disposition: attachment ? Обязательно ли собирать новое письмо (новый объект email.Message) и в него уже добавлять вложения ? Можно наверное как то изменить уже существующий обьект email.Message ? А если нельзя как можно сконструировать новое письмо которое может быть любой сложности(надо прокопировать все заголовки, все части письма например с помощью msg.walk) ?

Заранее огромное спасибо ! Я надеюсь что получу ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: Вмвашем примереивы добавили еще одну альтернативу в собщение типа multipart/alternative. Конечно же нет никаких гарантий, что клиент покажет именно вашу _альтернативу_. Вмобщем случае необходимо формировать новое письмо, заменяя тип контейнера с удаленным вирусом на текстовый с диагностикой. Дополнительно Это все можно обернуть в новое multipart/mixed письмо, в котором первая текстовая часть будет содержать уведомление об удаленных частях, а вторая message/rfc822 будет содержать в виде аттачмента оригинальное письмо с исправленными частями.

Answer (score 0):

[Если простая замена на текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/757881/23044), не работает в вашем случае, то чтобы заменить картинку на свой текст, не отслеживая где cid используется ([для вложенных по месту картинок в письме](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20485764/4279)), можно [сгенерировать свою картинку с нужным текстом и подставить её в то же место](https://ideone.com/eI4wiP):

```
import email.policy
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

for part in msg.walk():  # msg is EmailMessage
    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'image':
        # generate replacement image
        text = "name: {}, sha1: {}".format(
            part.get_filename() or 'unknown', sha1(part.get_content()))
        subtype = part.get_content_subtype()
        mime_image = MIMEImage(generate_image_data(text, subtype), subtype,
                               policy=email.policy.default)

        # replace
        part.set_payload(mime_image.get_payload())
        del part['Content-Type']  # NOTE: part.clear_content() removes too much
        del part['Content-Transfer-Encoding']
        del part['MIME-Version']
        for k, v in mime_image.items():  # copy new Content-Type, etc headers
            part[k] = v
```

Код ищет части в письме для замены (все картинки здесь), затем для каждой части генерирует картинку с текстом, содержащим имя файла и sha1 хэш и подставляет картинку, заменяя содержимое и копируя заголовки (чтобы правильные Content-Type, Сontent-Transfer-Encoding получить).

Где:

```
import hashlib

def sha1(data):
    return hashlib.sha1(data).hexdigest()
```

и:

```
import io
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont  # $ pip install pillow

def generate_image_data(text, type='png'):
    font = ImageFont.load_default()
    image = Image.new("RGB", font.getsize(text))
    ImageDraw.Draw(image).text((0, 0), text, font=font)
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(buffer, type)
    return buffer.getvalue()
```